# How to disable form options entirely within JS 'display:none' trick?

Tags: php, javascript, hidden-field

I have a form with multiple input values from various select drop down menus. For example:

A member has 3 choices:

Your favorite color: 1) red; 2 ) blue, 3) green.

If the favorite color selected is red, use a javascript show() to reveal a new div with drop down element, asking to select a new set of options (and so on for blue and green).

I am able to do this easily but the issue I run into however, is in the use of the additional form field names. For example, regardless of the selection above, every choice will prompt the user to enter information in a textarea explaining their choice. I want to name this text area: "explanation". If explanation is filled out by the member with choice 1 above, however, choice 3's hidden explanation field will overwrite the value, thus forcing me to create "explanation1", "explanation2", "explanation3"...

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish but ultimately, I do not want certain POST variables to go from page to page AT ALL within a hidden DIV. Is this possible?

Thanks!

## EDIT

I found [this article](http://techchorus.net/disable-and-enable-input-elements-div-block-using-jquery) which gives a good explanation for disabling input elements, it does not however get to my underlying basis which is that I want to have multiple input elements with the same name but appear only for various selections (so explanation is only valid if choices are 1,2,3 and 2,4 but just because 2,4 is not met, 'explanation' should not be set to disabled because of it)

Comment: you can't just use 1 textarea and not show/hide it?

Comment: @DampeS8N, please see the question again, I upped your answer for use in other areas but showing/hiding is not the issue. It is the fact that hidden or not, the HTML element is created. My edit may provide additional detail into the issue as elements can be shown using multiple routes (you must select 1,2,3,4 to show box A, or you can select 2,3 and box A is shown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the other fields (the hidden ones) to disabled? That way their values will not be posted along with the rest of your form.

So in the if-block where you decide which div-with-dropdown to show, just add:

```
$('#div1 .explanation, #div2 .explanation').attr('disabled', true);
```

Updated answer based on your comment. Just add a class to the answers, so they can have the same name. Make sure you don't give them the same ID, though. That's invalid HTML.

Comment: thanks Kander - i should have thought of this. I'll accept once the timer lets me

Comment: although, looking more closely - the thing I am trying to get around is this: i dont want to name my elements explanation1, explanation 2. I want the explanation field to be named as such for every hidden div. So the explanation box in div 3 is disabled, but explanation in 1 is not.

Comment: Updated answer. But I see below you don't want to use jQuery. That makes things a bit more complex - on modern browsers you can do getElementByClassname() or use Dean Edward's function by the same name. Otherwise, if there are no input elements inside the DIV that you do need to keep alive, then you can do a getElementsByTagName() on the DIV.

Comment: @kander - not that I don't want to use jquery necessarily, but completely rebuilding my page to post using ajax (which is a post regardless) is not a valid solution in my opinion.

Comment: Aaah, ok. You might want to look a bit better into what jQuery does, then. It doesn't require you to do rebuild the page... it just offers posting that way as an option. If you want to post some other way, you're still free to do that. It's a very relaxed 'take what you need'-framework :)

Comment: kander - based on the php validations we use it would require quite a bit of modification from our initial look but I'll give it another pass. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Man, it'll be very easy if you use Jquery, a JavaScript library. An example...

On a click, a input will appear...

```
$("#btn")click( function(){
    $("#inputID").css({'diplay':'block'});
});
```

You'll resolve your problems using Jquery.. access the site to learn more... http://www.jquery.com

Comment: if I understand what you are implying: the underlying html element is still created (correct?) and thus would generate the POST element for the hidden divs (even though they are empty)

Comment: Man... with Jquery you don't need to do posts. When an event occurs, the action is executed whithout postbacks.

Comment: the use of jquery here would mean applying additional ajax elements we would not otherwise utilize and completely re-scripting the page. I thank you for your answer but not necessarily looking to rebuild unless absolutely necessary.